# ASP.NET Model-View-Presenter and List versus Details

Tags: .net, asp.net, design-patterns, mvp, presenter

In Model-View-Presenter what is the correct pattern to do a page that:
a) contains a grid for browsing a list of items
b) an alternate mode for editing single items
maybe you are toggling between two asp:panels.

Do you just make the presenter smart enough to do two types of presentations?
Make 2 presenters?

I'm new to this pattern and want to do it correctly. I understand how I would do this functionality on two pages. Just not sure what is the accepted practice when the browse and detail exist on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an edit view a user control and have a presenter for it.